# Error with R parallel implementation: object of type closure is not subsettale

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I am working on an implementation of a Monte Carlo scheme. 
I apply this simulation for different datasets contained in the dataframe *df*. For one dataset, the function *MCdetermination()* computes the value of interest. To reduce running time I want to make use of the package doParallel.

When I set the input values and run each line of the code by hand everything works perfectly, but when I call the function by MCfullsimulation(...) I get the error

*Error during wrapup: task 1 failed - "object of type 'closure' is not subsettale"*

Also, without parallel computation (i.e. %do% instead of %dopar% ) everything works when calling the function. 
What did I do wrong? I am not used to work on multiple cores. Please help me.

```
MCfullsimulation <- function(df, r, J){
  source("MCdetermination.R")
  library(doParallel)
  cl <- makeCluster(2)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  v0 <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(df), .export = c('MCdetermination'), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
      MCdetermination(df[i,], r, J)
    }
  return(v0)
}
```

Comment: That error is common when (1) you re-use a `function` name for a regular variable, and (2) have code that uses that variable but has not instantiated it correctly. In this case, the error can be reproduced with `df[1]` (when `df` is just the F distribution density function). I suspect that somehow your `df` is not being transferred correctly to the clients. Try renaming `df` to something unambiguous such as `dat`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was not the variable `df` itself, but it was exactly this kind of mistake. I used a variable in the function `MCdetermination` which I did not input and that is also defined as a function. It is working now, thanks.